# Why is req.body always empty when using Postman to call Express using JSON?

Tags: json, express, postman

I have a simple express server set up like this...

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
import express from "express";  // eslint-disable-line
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

export class BaseApp{
    constructor(port){
        const p = port || PORT;
        this.express = express();
        this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.express.listen(p, (err)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
            return console.log(`Healthcheck server is listening on ${port}`);
        });
    }
}

const SearchRoute = function(app) {
    const Router = express.Router();
    const HANDLE_POST = (req, res)=> {
        console.log("Metadata is " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
        res.send("done");
    };
    Router.post("/", HANDLE_POST);
    app.use("/search", Router);
};
export class SearchApp extends BaseApp{
    constructor(){
        super(PORT);
        SearchRoute(this.express);
    }
}
new SearchApp(); // eslint-disable-line no-new
```

When I run and use postman (On raw with application/json selected) and submit via post the terminal displays...

```
Metadata is {}
```

even though my body was...

[image]

I have confirmed my header is correct

[image]

Why is the body empty?

Comment: Another note, if I convert over to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it is working but I need json

Comment: Also curl works fine so I am changing the title

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your content-type header with "application/json" instead of "application/javascript"